# Can Backup Exec 2010 Policy "steps" be bound to specific selection lists?

Tags: backup, sql, backupexec

I'm trying to make a policy like this:

Step 1: Backup everything in full

Step 2: Come back and do transaction log backups on SQL/Sharepoint (with truncate)

Step 3: Verify Backups.

But when it comes time to select selection lists (upon policy saving) and I select both my "full" backup selection list and my "SQL/Sharepoint only" selection list I get two jobs per step of the policy.

Of course, because of this all my files are backed up twice (since I didn't modify the "general" backup parameters for files, it's still set to "FULL" in the job step.   But the intention of that selection list is to ONLY grab SQL/Sharepoint data.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No, a policy is applied to a selection list in its entirety.

What you want is one policy that is just what you want for backing up files, and one policy that is just what you want for SQL.

Then you have two selection lists - one with files in, and the other with SQL databases in. It's obvious which selection list goes with which policy!

This might seem like more work initially, but as your environment becomes more complex, you'll realise that it's much easier this way. You may end up with lots of jobs, but as long as you manage the policies and selection lists, it'll all work out.